# Extracting the two smallest values corresponding to the unique-to-the-column ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I have two rows, that is: `ID` and `Time`. I want to extract the two smallest Time value corresponding to the unique column ID.

```
ID  Time
27604   13:00:12
27604   13:00:32
27604   13:00:34
27604   13:00:38
27604   13:00:41
27604   13:00:47
27604   13:00:50
27605   13:00:20
27605   13:00:23
27605   13:00:39
27605   13:00:42
27605   13:00:45
27605   13:00:48
27605   13:00:54
27605   13:00:57
27605   13:01:00
27606   13:00:49
27606   13:00:52
27606   13:00:55
27606   13:01:01
27606   13:01:04
27606   13:01:07
```

> For ID 27604 I want to extract 13:00:12 and 13:00:32 only.
>
> For ID 27605 I want to extract 13:00:20 and 13:00:23 only.
>
> For ID 27606 I want to extract 13:00:27 and 13:00:30 only.

I want to extract all this values as below:

```
27604   13:00:12
27604   13:00:32
27605   13:00:20
27605   13:00:23
27606   13:00:49
27606   13:00:52
```

Comment: use advanced fillters

Comment: can you post your workouts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) values (with criteria) easily with the [AGGREGATE¹ function's](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) [SMALL sub-function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) (e.g. 15).

[image: AGGREGATE MINIF]

The formula in E4 is,

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, (B:B)/(A:A=D4), COUNTIF(D$4:D4, D4))
```

Fill down as necessary. Since we are using the SMALL sub-function, we can easily retrieve the second, third, etc. ratios by increasing the *k* parameter as I've done with a [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) implementing a progressive range and floating criteria.

The **6** is the AGGREGATE parameter for ignoring error values. By dividing the time by whether or not column A is the correct ID we are producing `#DIV/0!` errors for anything we do not want considered leaving them ignored.

¹<sub>The [AGGREGATE¹ function's](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in previous versions.</sub>

Comment: I would just add that I'd strongly recommend not referencing entire columns. You could be looking at a million-plus unnecessary calculations that way. And that's just considering one iteration of that formula. Copied down to just 50 or so rows would, I imagine, practically crash Excel.

Comment: Fair enough. I really should be more judicious when offering up full column references.

Comment: I think it's more a case of knowing with which functions you can "get away" with using entire column references, i.e. COUNTIF(S), SUMIF(S). With array-processing functions (SUMPRODUCT, AGGREGATE, etc., plus any construction requiring CSE) it's disastrous.

Answer (score 0):

I used this array formula starting in C2 to get the pairs of ID's

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$10,MATCH(TRUE,(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,A$2:A$10)<2),0)),"")
```

and this one starting in D2 to get the first two times

```
=SMALL(IF(A$2:A$10=C2,B$2:B$10),COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2))
```

must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

tested on a subset of data. Must be at least two times for each ID.

Should work on most versions of Excel.

[image]