# How to solve issue of identical items while using Index Match in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have data in a column as in this image:

[image]

I then rearranged column J in descending order like this:

[image]

Now when I used Index-Match `=INDEX(L$4:L$193,MATCH(J203,J$4:J$193,0),0)`, it matches with corresponding value in column L & return the value. But the problem is when I arrange values in column J and if they are identical e.g. 2052 "image 2" index-match returns the first value it encountered with 2052, there are other values also for the same 2052 but it won't fetch them. How to solve this issue?

Comment: index/match only returns one item...

Comment: Do you have an additional value you can use as the Match? You can run index/match with multiple criteria.

Comment: see [Searching rows for two entries and returning the successful results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784528/searching-rows-for-two-entries-and-returning-the-successful-results-adapting-ex/32785125#32785125).

Comment: maybe [Extracting the two smallest values corresponding to the unique-to-the-column ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134569/extracting-the-two-smallest-values-corresponding-to-the-unique-to-the-column-id/32134864#32134864) would be better.

Comment: What do you want to do if you have more than one? Do you want to process to a single result (e.g. average, max, min)? Return them all - where is this formula going, any rules for number of results etc.?

Comment: @Captain I want to sum them & I want all the values corresponding the that specific match/number. let's say for 2052 if there are values like 507, 31, 109, 205, 82 etc. I want 'em all no only 507 which was the first value after arrangement.

Comment: "How" do you want them? At multiple lines or separated by `,` in one cell?

Comment: @Dirk in multiple line. in one column one by one.

Comment: Why not use `=SUBTOTAL(9,L$4:L$193)` and filter the list at column `J`? This way you will only see the lines you want and also have the sum of them (excluding the hidden rows)...

Answer (score 0):

Index-match returns only one value. If you want to get the nth value, you'll have to do something like:

```
{=INDEX(COLUMN_L,SMALL(IF(COLUMN_J=LOOKUPVALUE,ROW(COLUMN_J)-ROW(INDEX(COLUMN_J,1,1))+1),NTH_VALUE))}
```

Basically this will return the nth value. The downside is that you must now ahead of time how many such values you hope to retrieve. You could pre-program such a column (1,2,3,4...nth) and have each of these return next to it the corresponding result.

You may want to add IFERROR(....) wrapper, since if there's only one value it'll raise an error for the 2nd, 3rd, etc.

This may be slightly unstatisfactory - I was looking for the same thing once and the best I could do was the above.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment "I want to sum them", then you can use the `SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])` function... i.e. `SUMIF(J$4:J$193,J203,L$4:L$193)`